# Javascript Isn't Working With Owl-Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, owl-carousel

I have been trying to implement a carousel for my website for 5 hours now. I want to display multiple images but increment the carousel by 1 image each time. I tried following this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVNv1jUitCk until 4:45. Everything shows up fine except the previous and next buttons do not show up. I am convinced that Javascript is not working on my system, but it could be another problem. This is my 5th tutorial. Also, i dont know how to link the owl library here as it is downloaded to my local computer.

watched multiple tutorials and searched through stack overflow

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/base.css"> -->

    <!-- linking the owl carousel files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/owl.theme.default.css">

    <title>Carousel Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>




    <!-- carousel -->
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
              <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
              <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!-- linking owl js here -->
    <script src="../static/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>

    <!-- owl setup script -->
    <script>
      $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
          loop:true,
          margin:10,
          nav:true,
          responsive:{
              0:{
                  items:1
              },
              600:{
                  items:3
              },
              1000:{
                  items:5
              }
          }
      })
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

expected results should be a carousel with two buttons, next and prev, that actually works.

Comment: which version of own you use and try use this with cdn first

Answer (score 0):

I just tried loading up Owl-Carousel with the HTML code you supplied and it works (I adjusted the file paths to match my own). However, if you did not link your files correctly it is likely some components will not load correctly (like the arrows in your case).

If you open dev tools and head to 'console', do you see any error message in there? That will give you a clue as to what might not be loading correctly.

Comment: Robhyrk, yes the file path is good. I used auto complete on vscode for the file path so I know it’s there. I believe the js file is defective because I switched it to use the CDN’s owl-carousel file and it worked perfectly. Maybe I downloaded an older version of the files.